HTTP Toolkit interception with Android emulator interfering: app not working when enabled
This issue is like this one from more than one year ago.
I am intercepting HTTP traffic from an Android app using HTTP Toolkit via the Android Emulator. Everything was working a few weeks ago, but now, when I enable interception, the apps stop working as expected. Funny thing is that it is also failing on default apps, like Google Maps (see here)
I've tried:

Creating a new Android Emulator image (ensuring it is not "Google Play").
Different Android API levels (30, 31, 33).
Ensuring my app is not using certificate pinning.
Ensuring my app uses standard HTTPS calls.
Using a different computer.

The result is always the same: with HTTP interception on, the app does not work. Stopping interception, the app works again.

How long have you had HTTP Toolkit open? If you haven't completely restarted the app in many days, it's possible the certificate has expired. It's only refreshed when the app is completely restarted (note that on Mac, closing a window doesn't close the app - you have to quit). If you try to use a browser on your device, does it show any kind of certificate details or errors there?

I've tried restarting windows and also completely reinstalling HTTP Toolkit with the latest version. I've tried this on three different computers, with different Android versions on the emulator (from 9 to 14), and the result is always the same: when interception is on, some apps stop working as expected. The app I am testing is doing a call to the server, but then it is stuck. If I disable interception, it works flawlessly.
Funny thing is that it was working a month ago. Can't figure out what is happening.
Is it necessary to setup something else on the emulator to work?

No, nothing else should be required on the emulator in general. What's shown in HTTP Toolkit on your computer? If traffic is reaching your machine, you should see either an 'aborted connection'/'certificate rejected' empty row (meaning this is a client certificate trust issue) or an HTTP request (potentially with some kind of error) in which case the client setup is OK and something else (e.g. an upstream connection problem, or a rule you've added breaking things) is causing the issue. If nothing appears at all, it's a proxy connection issue.

in fact, I see you're at UAB - I'm in Barcelona too! In Gracia. Do you want to come show me the problem some time next week? This is definitely unusual & worth investigating, I'm happy to take a look and debug properly. Pick any time: https://calendly.com/httptoolkit-tim/60min

Great! I already picked a time. Thank you!
